# How to change value of >= to ascii character in TypeScript file

Tags: angular, typescript, ascii, setter

I'm trying to check if a string has >= and then, if so, replace that with the ascii character for greater than and equal to. I'm working in Angular in the TS file and currently have:

```
@Input()
  public set textLabel(value: string) {
  let labelSymbols = value
  // figure out how to check if string has >=
  // if string has >=, replace with ASCII character
  this._textLabel = labelSymbols

  this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
  public get textLabel(): string {
    return this._textLabel
  }
  private _textLabel: string;
```

What do I need to do to change the greater than and equal to when it occurs in the string?

Comment: Your question does not make sens. You are trying to check if string has >=, but greater or equals to what ? It's not clear what you are trying to compare.

Comment: Do you just mean a literal `>=`?  In which case just check the substr index is not -1, like in JS

Comment: I'm trying to check if the value contains the symbols ">=". I need to replace every instance of the symbols ">=" with ≥

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @BRAvery just so you know, ≥ isn't an ASCII character. It is a Unicode character however

Comment: Also, the `let labelSymbols = value` assignment feels really unnecessary. Just do the operations directly on `value`. Rename it to `labelSymbols` if you prefer

Answer (score 1):

From the info I got from your comment, you are simply looking for a search and replace. You can use the `replaceAll` function to do that.

```js
function replaceAllGreaterOrEqualsChar(input) {
  return input.replaceAll('>=', '≥');
}

const originalString = "this is >= a test, with >= multiple instances.";

// we pass the original string in our custom function,
const output = replaceAllGreaterOrEqualsChar(originalString);

// we print the results to the console.
console.log('output', output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression, `/>=/g` to find every occurrence of `>=` and replace it with `≥`, as shown in the below code snippet,

```js
@Input()
public set textLabel(value: string) {
  let regexToMatch = />=/g
  this._textLabel = value.replace(regexToMatch, "≥");;

  this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}

public get textLabel(): string {
  return this._textLabel
}

private _textLabel: string;
```

Comment: The square brackets in that regex do nothing, you can just use `/>=/g`.